# React Native navigation get param as an array and map the array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to change data between 2 different screens using react-navigation. The default screen shows the notes and adding the note is done in a separate screen using text input. Adding screen needs to give an array to default screen.

I managed to give some parameter but adding screen should pass an array.

Adding note class. Text input makes a new addition to notes state.

```
class AddScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
  state = {
    textInputComponent: '',
    notes: [
     {
       text: "Note 1"
     }
    ]
  }
return(
<View>
    <TextInput style = {styles.inputField} placeholder="Write the note here"
    onChangeText={(textInputComponent) => this.setState({textInputComponent})}
    value = {this.state.textInputComponent} />
    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.customBtn2}
      onPress={() => {this.addToList(this.state.textInputComponent)}}>
      <Text style = {styles.customBtnText}>Add note </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.customBtn3}
      onPress={() => navigate('Notes', {note: this.state.notes})}>
      <Text style = {styles.customBtnText2}>Add notes </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
);
```

The default screen where notes should be showing

```
class NoteList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        notes: []
        }
  }
makeNoteList(note){
    this.state.notes.push(note);
    console.log(this.state.notes);
      return (
        <View>
   {this.state.notes.map(note => {console.log(note.text)})}
        </View>
        )
    }
render() {
const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
const {navigation} = this.props;
const note = navigation.getParam('note', 'No notes');

return(
<ScrollView style = {styles.background}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, 
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center'}}>
{this.makeNoteList(note)}  
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, 
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end'}} >
    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.customBtn}
      onPress={() => navigate('AddNotes', {name: 'AddNotes'})}>
      <Text style = {styles.customBtnText}>List of notes </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
)
}
}
```

I can't seem to map the parameters that AddScreen class gives. Default screen should map this given array to show notes. I'm aware that these code snippets are missing some curly brackets and maybe brackets to shorten these snippets so here you can see the whole code: https://snack.expo.io/rk4opjbqE

Comment: I would love to help you if you create a minimal version of your app in https://snack.expo.io/ and share the link. There are lots of issues with you code. It would be easier if you share the whole app (minimal version)

Comment: Sure, here is the link: https://snack.expo.io/rk4opjbqE. I also forgot to mention that the app should be stored in the application's memory, so I think that React states could work for that.